# Calc Problem with Expressing A Sum with Natural Log

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

So I've tried expressing this in a few different ways but online I've only found solutions in log base 10...

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(\frac{1}{3})^n + (\frac{2}{3})^n}{n^2}$

The question is to express this in the form $\frac{Q\pi^W+Eln(R)ln(T)+Y(ln(U))^I}{O}$. Is there something I'm missing? Thanks

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $-1\le x<1$, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{n}=-\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}$.  Integration reveals

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n}}{n^2}=-\int_0^x \frac{\log(1-t)}t\,dt=\text{Li}_2(x)$$

where $\text{Li}_2(x)=-\int_0^x \frac{\log(1-t)}{t}\,dt$ is the [dilogarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function).

Therefore, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left(\frac13\right)^n+\left(\frac23\right)^n}{n^2}&=-\int_0^{1/3} \frac{\log(1-t)}t\,dt-\int_0^{2/3} \frac{\log(1-t)}t\,dt\\\\
&=\text{Li}_2(1/3)+\text{Li}_2(2/3)\\\\
&=\text{Li}_2(1/3)+\text{Li}_2(1-1/3)\\\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\log(1/3)\log(2/3)
\end{align}$$

where we used the identity $\text{Li}_2(x)+\text{Li}_2(1-x)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\log(x)\log(1-x)$.

Comment: Hi Mark ! Long time no see

Comment: Hi Claude.  How are you?  I still check in occasionally, but the composition of types of questions on MSE has really changed a lot since I joined as a member.  And I don't find interest or expertise in my answering most of the current types.

Comment: @MarkViola: Nice answer and interesting approach. (+1)

Comment: @MarkusScheuer Much appreciated Markus.  I hope you're doing well.